# Get all first level folders of archive module run

Tags: ansible

I'm using the `archive` module to zip some folders and archives.
I need to list all first level folders inside my zip file.

Is there any Jinja or python function to do this using the registered output of the `archive` module?

My test, so far are:

```
- name: zip folder
  archive:
    path: 
      - /tmp/test/*
    dest: /tmp/zipfile.zip
    format: zip
    mode: "0755"
    force_archive: true
  register: module_result
```

Printing `module_result`, I get:

```
ok: [host1] => 


msg:
    ansible_facts:
      discovered_interpreter_python: /usr/bin/python
    archived:
    - /tmp/test/cfg/1.txt
    - /tmp/test/cfg/2.txt
    - /tmp/test/cfg/3.txt
    - /tmp/test/folder1/folder2/4.txt
    - /tmp/test/folder1/folder2/5.txt
```

Using another task to show my attempts:

```
- name: list folders
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item.lstrip(module_result.arcroot).split('/')[0] }}"
    # msg: "{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{module_result.archived}}"
```

I'm trying to cut the first part of the url, using `module_result.arcroot` on every item that module outputs me and then, a split of the rest of the path, but I get a wrong result. And the worst part is that I'm getting too many times the same folder name.

And the result:

```
cfg
cfg
cfg
folder1
folder1
```

My expected result would be:

```
cfg
folder1
```

Is this possible?

Comment: How is you result wrong? First result = for file 1.txt; second for 2.txt, third for 3.txt, fourth for 4.txt and fifth for 5.txt. So the result is right, no?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to achieve an unicity on the folders of first level, then the [`unique`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#unique) Jinja filter is what you are looking for.

Since this filter acts on lists, you would then need to, first, register your results as a list, via the module [`set_fact`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/set_fact_module.html).

```
- name: Making a list out of the files first folder
  set_fact: 
    folders: "{{ folders | default([]) + [(item.lstrip(faked_module_result_arcroot).split('/')[0])] }}"
  with_items: "{{ faked_module_result_archived }}"
```

Then just use the Jinja filter:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ folders | unique }}"
```

Fully working playbook:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  vars:
    faked_module_result_archived:
      - /tmp/test/cfg/1.txt
      - /tmp/test/cfg/2.txt
      - /tmp/test/cfg/3.txt
      - /tmp/test/folder1/folder2/4.txt
      - /tmp/test/folder1/folder2/5.txt
    faked_module_result_arcroot: /tmp/test/

  tasks:
    - name: Making an list out of the files first folder
      set_fact: 
        folders: "{{ folders | default([]) + [(item.lstrip(faked_module_result_arcroot).split('/')[0])] }}"
      with_items: "{{ faked_module_result_archived }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ folders | unique }}"
```

Would output

```
PLAY [localhost] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Making an list out of the files first folder] ************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/test/cfg/1.txt)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/test/cfg/2.txt)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/test/cfg/3.txt)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/test/folder1/folder2/4.txt)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/test/folder1/folder2/5.txt)

TASK [debug] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "cfg",
        "folder1"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example works great! I could get some tips and tricks to customize mi script, but for some reason, I'm am getting a strange lstrip behavior when I run the adaptation.

Here is my code:

```
- name: zip a folder
  archive:
    path: 
    - /tmp/test/*
    dest: /tmp/{{ path_example | basename }}-files.zip
    exclude_path:
    - /tmp/test/another_folder
    format: zip
    mode: "0755"
    force_archive: true
   register: module_result

- name: First, lstrip result
    set_fact: 
      lstrip_result: "{{ lstrip_result | default([]) [(item.lstrip(module_result.arcroot))] }}"
    with_items: "{{ module_result.archived }}"
```

After run "Archive" task:

```
ok: [desa01] => changed=false
ansible_facts:
  discovered_interpreter_python: /usr/bin/python
archived:
    - /tmp/test/cfg/1.txt
    - /tmp/test/cfg/2.txt
    - /tmp/test/cfg/3.txt
    - /tmp/test/folder1/folder2/4.txt
    - /tmp/test/folder1/folder2/5.txt
arcroot: /tmp/test/
dest: /tmp/lelo/test-files.zip
expanded_exclude_paths:
- /tmp/test/another_folder
```

After run "First, lstrip result" task:

```
TASK [task2: First remove arcroot using lstrip ] ********************************************************************************************************
ok: [desa01] => (item=/tmp/test/cfg/1.txt) => changed=false
  ansible_facts:
    lstrip_result:
    - cfg/1.txt
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item: /tmp/test/cfg/1.txt
ok: [desa01] => (item=/tmp/test/cfg/2.txt) => changed=false
  ansible_facts:
    lstrip_result:
    - cfg/1.txt
    - cfg/2.txt
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item: /tmp/test/cfg/2.txt
ok: [desa01] => (item=/tmp/test/cfg/3.txt) => changed=false
  ansible_facts:
    lstrip_result:
    - cfg/1.txt
    - cfg/2.txt
    - cfg/3.txt
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item: /tmp/test/cfg/3.txt
ok: [desa01] => (item=/tmp/test/folder1/folder2/4.txt) => changed=false
  ansible_facts:
   lstrip_result:
    - cfg/1.txt
    - cfg/2.txt
    - cfg/3.txt
    - st/folder1/folder2/4.txt
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item: /tmp/test/folder1/folder2/4.txt
ok: [desa01] => (item=/tmp/test/folder1/folder2/5.txt) => changed=false
  ansible_facts:
    lstrip_result:
    - cfg/1.txt
    - cfg/2.txt
    - cfg/3.txt
    - st/folder1/folder2/4.txt
    - st/folder1/folder2/4.txt
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item: /tmp/test/folder1/folder2/5.txt
```

Here is my problem, with folder cfg everything it is ok, but with folder test, lstrip function is like striping 2 chars more than expected and the result is:

```
st/folder...
```

instead of:

```
test/folder...
```

Someone gets an idea of this strange lstrip out??

**EDIT**

lstrip doc says:

Definition and Usage
The lstrip() method **removes any leading characters** (space is the default leading character to remove)

That's why my output was bad striped, becouse some chars where repited in the string.

I replace **lstrip** with **replace**

```
- name: First, lstrip result
    set_fact: 
      lstrip_result: "{{ lstrip_result | default([]) [(item.lstrip(module_result.arcroot))] }}"
    with_items: "{{ module_result.archived }}"
```